# Expo Video Not Loading Dynamic URI

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm having trouble with the expo video component. It works perfectly fine when I insert the URI directly like this:

```
    source={{
      uri: 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/vably6/intro.mp4?raw=1',
    }}
```

However when I insert the source dynamically, it plays about 25% of the time.

```
    source={{
      uri: `${player}`,
    }}
```

What could be causing the inconsistent loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

However if your `player` variable is from any state then you have to make sure before rendering the component you should put a condition like this:

```
if(player) return // The code related to the video.
```

And if your player variable is still empty then:

```
if(!player) reuturn // Some kind of loading spinner
```

Comment: This plus removing the ${} and simply typing uri: player solved the issue. Thank you!